# How to redirect in rails if route matches regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I have two routes in routes.rb

```
get 'schools/*criteria', to: 'schools#show'
// need this route to redirect to above route
get 'schools/*criteria/school-[a-zA-z]' ,to: redirect('schools/*criteria', status: 301)
```

Ex: when I try this url **/schools/elementary/school-c** it has to redirect to **/schools/elementary**. but it is not happening.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `constraint` and pass `title` to params

```
get 'schools/*criteria/:title', constraint: { title: /school-[a-zA-z]/ }, to: redirect('schools/%{criteria}/%{title}', status: 301)
```